# Combine two ansible tasks but run only one based on condition and register result

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Team,

I have a situation of running one task out of two based on condition `when` result and both are exact same but just that expression is different.

tasks

```
  - name: Create partitions WHEN it is NVME device
    parted:
      device: "{{ item.0.device }}"
      number: "{{ item.1.number }}"
      part_start: "{{ item.1.start }}"
      part_end: "{{ item.1.end }}"
      state: present
    loop:  "{{ local_volume_mount_disks|subelements('partitions') }}"
    when: '"{{item.0.device }}" is regex("nvme\w+")'
    register: partitioned_device_live_info

  - name: Create partitions WHEN it is SD* device
    parted:
      device: "{{ item.0.device }}"
      number: "{{ item.1.number }}"
      part_start: "{{ item.1.start }}"
      part_end: "{{ item.1.end }}"
      state: present
    loop:  "{{ local_volume_mount_disks|subelements('partitions') }}"
    when: '"{{item.0.device }}" is regex("sd\w+")'
    register: partitioned_device_live_info
```

But what is happening is the register variable `partitioned_device_live_info` is being replaced by result of its task result. So, I want to retain the results in registered variable PASS results. is there a way, I can join these two tasks such that register variable once is filled is not replaced when `when` is false?

something like Task1 `when` is true, register variable has its result, then task2 is checked but register variable is skipped and not replaced. because I need to continue with other tasks with that variable having certain value which i get only when `when` is TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Yes there is an ugly solution but also no this is expected behavior. Ugly solution below:

Use the set-fact on a when basis

```
- name: Create partitions WHEN it is NVME device
    parted:
      device: "{{ item.0.device }}"
      number: "{{ item.1.number }}"
      part_start: "{{ item.1.start }
      part_end: "{{ item.1.end }}"
      state: present
    loop:  "{{ local_volume_mount_disks|subelements('partitions') }}"
    when: '"{{item.0.device }}" is regex("nvme\w+")'
    register: tmp

- set_fact: partitioned_device_live_info ="{{tmp}}"
    when: tmp.changed

  - name: Create partitions WHEN it is SD* device
    parted:
      device: "{{ item.0.device }}"
      number: "{{ item.1.number }}"
      part_start: "{{ item.1.start }}"
      part_end: "{{ item.1.end }}"
      state: present
    loop:  "{{ local_volume_mount_disks|subelements('partitions') }}"
    when: '"{{item.0.device }}" is regex("sd\w+")'
    register: tmp


- set_fact: partitioned_device_live_info ="{{tmp}}"
    when: tmp.changed
```